# Sliding a navbar-fixed-bottom left off screen and back

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

The "problem behind this problem" is that I want a navigational bar along the bottom of my site.  I want to be able to put a button on this bar that causes the bar to slide right almost all the way off the screen.  The leftover part of the bar would be the button that slides it back onto the screen again.

The site uses Bootstrap 3 for layout, so I'm trying to implement this with a "navbar-fixed-bottom" that has the close button on it.  I'd like to use the Boostrap grid inside the nav bar, so that I can lay out the icons the way I want to.  (Although the close button will probably break the grid or sit outside of it somehow - it needs to be smaller and all the way to the left for this to work)

My jQuery code for sliding is coming from this site: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions/

My jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8JLXw/4/

The issue that I'm having is that the contents of the navbar "squish" upwards instead of sliding offscreen.  The reference site says that the fix for this is to set the parent element of the sliding element to be `overflow:hidden` and the example shows this working properly.

I dutifully wrapped my nav in a div with `overflow:hidden` and this hasn't helped.  I'm guessing either I'm doing it wrong or there's something about Bootstrap that is preventing this from working properly.  I'm not opposed to not using the built-in `navbar-fixed-bottom` if it simplifies things.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a width to your nav:

```
#mynav {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This works, but I'm not certain as to why it does.  What did I miss that I could learn from for the next time?

Comment: the nav takes up as much space as there is room for. When it slides right there is no space. By adding the width, you tell it to take up as much space as the parent of it.